# Determining the limit of a function containing $(x-1)^5$ without l'hopital`s rule.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find the limit of $$\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}
\frac{(x-1)^5 + (1 + 5x)}{x^2 + x^5}
\end{equation*}$$

Shall I use the binomial theorem? 
Any hint will be appreciated!

Comment: You know about the binomial theorem, and you came here to ask whether you should apply it? Why don't you apply it yourself and see what happens?  The worst that can happen is that you find that that approach doesn't work. The best that can happen is that you find the solution.

Comment: I guess. You can calculate $(x-1)^5$ by making the four multiplications, if you so desire. Your time, your choice.

Comment: Wait, how come OP's asked questions on $R$-modules but doesn't seem to know how to do high school calculus?

Comment: Strangely enough, the hardest thing for most students in calculus class isn't the calculus, it's the algebra.  I recommend looking at Pascal's triangle again, because it's a great technique for expanding binomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now that OP's conditions are better known, let's try again.

Numerator is 
$$(x-1)^5+(1+5x)\equiv x^5-5x^4+10x^3-10x^2+5x-1+(1+5x)$$$$\equiv x^5-5x^4+10x^3-10x^2+10x$$

so the given expression is

$$\frac{x^5-5x^4+10x^3-10x^2+10x}{x^5+x^2}\equiv\frac{x^4-5x^3+10x^2-10x+10}{x^4+x}.$$

Now, numerator does not approach $0$ as $x\to 0$ but denominator does, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: How is L'Hopital's rule helpful if the limit does not exist? And do you know the statement of L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: In the example given, the limit of f(x) is not 0.

Comment: Maybe I should have made it clear that it works if the limits exists but is unhelpful otherwise. Edited.

Comment: Yup, I've miscalculated.

Comment: Sorry, I mean + not - , I will edit it

Comment: I'll just edit a L'Hopital thingee here again when you've changed it :)

Comment: I have mentioned "without l`hopital`s rule"

Comment: In the tag and not the question?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

Divide top and bottom by $x^2$ to get $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x^2}(1+5x) + \frac{1}{x^2}(x-1)^5}{1+x^3}$$

This is a quotient where the denominator has limit $1$, so the limit exists iff the following limit exists, and it has the same value as this limit: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \left[\frac{1}{x^2}(1+5x) + \frac{1}{x^2}(x-1)^5\right]$$

Now this can be done using the binomial theorem; alternatively, substitute $u=x^2$ to get $$\lim_{u \to 0} \left[\frac{(1+5\sqrt{u})+(\sqrt{u}-1)^5}{u} \right]$$
which is the derivative of the function $y \mapsto (1+5 \sqrt{y}) + (\sqrt{y} - 1)^5$ at $y=0$; that derivative is easily evaluated and its limit to $0$ taken, and that limit is manifestly $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering $$\frac{(x-1)^5 + (1 + 5x)}{x^2 + x^5}$$ the $1$ will cancel out (because of power $5$ in numerator) and you are left with terms in $x$ for the lowest degree in numerator. So 
$$\frac{(x-1)^5 + (1 + 5x)}{x^2 + x^5}\sim \frac{kx+\cdots}{x^2}\sim \frac k x$$